# Laravel table in a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel-5

I have this site with a form in it. Here I ask the user for their language skills.

First I built it like a list:

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="request_profile_languages">
          @isset($requestProfile)
            @foreach($requestProfile->languages as $index=>$requestProfileLanguage)
              <li>
                <select {{ (FALSE == $canEdit) ? 'readonly':'' }} class="form-control form-select" id="{{ 'request_profile_language_'.$index }}" name="{{ 'request_profile_language_'.$index }}" placeholder="Language">
                  @foreach($languages as $r=>$language)
                    <option {{ ($language->name == $requestProfileLanguage->language->name) ? 'selected':'' }} value="{{ $language->value }}" >{{ $language->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </li>
            @endforeach
          @else
            <li>
              <select {{ (FALSE == $canEdit) ? 'readonly':'' }} class="form-control form-select" id="request_profile_language_0" name="request_profile_language_0" placeholder="Language">
                @foreach($languages as $r=>$language)
                  <option {{ ($language->name == 'English') ? 'selected':'' }} value="{{ $language->value }}" >{{ $language->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </li>
          @endisset
        </ul>
      </div>
```

There are more divs with language level and language remove.

The problem is on site, when I minimize the browser, it looks like this:

[Language List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTTOF.png)

I want a table replacing this list. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have your list in a `.col-md-3` div. If you change it to a `.col-xs-something` and put the x's in a `.column-xs` beside it, then they should still match up. I'm assuming that's how it is on larger devices since you didn't post the html for the x's?